# jQuery AJAX function on success not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Having an issue.  I have two different buttons included with each image displayed.  One is remove, the other is assign as "main".

Remove works.  It hides the image, deletes the file, and the MySQL row.

Assign Main sort of works.  It updates the row in the database changing "main" value to 1, as it should, however, it should also alert(), but it does not.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove_image").click(function() {

        var image_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"imagecontrol.php",
            data: { image_id:image_id,
                    image_remove:1},
            success: function(response) {
                $('#image_'+image_id).fadeOut(400);
                showUploader();
            }
        })

    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".assign_main").click(function() {

        var assign_this_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"imagecontrol.php",
            data: { assign_this_id:assign_this_id,
                    image_assign:1},
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        })
    })
});

</script>
```

Comment: Add an error handler and see if it is triggered.

Comment: Check also the php logs. There might be an error which is making the process fail.

Comment: It's likely that your server is telling the browser that the request failed, even if it's successfully making the update in the database.

Comment: I added , error: function() { alert("Error"); } ... Nothing

Comment: Oh, that's weird! I recommend adding that to the body of the question, since  all the current answers assume you haven't tried that.

Comment: Sounds like this is inside a form and default submit is sending the data. Is page refreshing each time? Try preventing default in the click handler. Also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: Watching the Network tab on dev tools, on click of Remove button, I see a response from imagecontrol.php is received, but with assign_main, I see a record going to imagecontrol.php, but it never receives anything, and the row disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` method is only called when a `HTTP 200` or `HTTP 304` is returned, therefore you may need to double check to see if this is actually the case.

This can be done in the ‘Inspector’ panel in most modern web browsers, usually under the ‘Network’ tab.

You can also add a `error: function() {}` event handler to catch any HTTP 4xx / 5xx codes.

Answer (score -1):

Use `done()` instead of it :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "imagecontrol.php",
    data: {
        image_id: image_id,
        image_remove: 1
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    $('#image_' + image_id).fadeOut(400);
    showUploader();
);
```

Comment: why would this help if success callback isn't firing?

Answer (score -1):

Try and alert the error which for sure is there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".assign_main").click(function() {

        var assign_this_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"imagecontrol.php",
            data: { assign_this_id:assign_this_id,
                image_assign:1},
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

This will show you if there is something wrong in your PHP code